# Writing function to count number of NA values in vector while ignoring specified indices

Tags: r, function, vector, na

I am trying to write a function to count the number of `NA` values in a vector (specified in the first argument) that will also ignore some indices (specified in a second argument) when making the count.

For example, if I have
    `x = c(1,NA,3,4,NA,6,NA,8,9)`

I want to us a function like
    `countNA(vector = x, ignore = c(5,7))`
and return a count of 1 (the function is told to ignore `x[5]` and `x[7]`

This is what I've tried so far, but it isn't working:

```
countNA.2 = function(x, ignore){ 
    #define a function with arguments "x" (vector to be searched for NAs) 
    #and "ignore" vector indices to be ignored if NA
    count = c() #define empty vector to hold the counts of na in vector x
    t = c(1:9) #define a reference vector to represent possible indicies
    #(max vector length is 9)
    for (q in t){ #loop through our possible vector indicies
        ifelse(q %in% ignore, count[q] = 0, count[q] = is.na(x[q])) 
        #if index is in ignore vector, then set count[q] = 0 
        #else, set count[q] = TRUE for NA and FALSE otherwise
    }
    numoccurrences = sum(count) #after we're done, sum our count vector
    return(numoccurrences) #return
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the values from the vector and take the `sum` of `is.na`:

```
cntNA <- function(x, ignore) sum(is.na(x[-(ignore)]))
cntNA(x, ignore=c(5,7))
#[1] 1
```

If you want to account for `ignore` not being specified, just add an `if/else` condition:

```
cntNA <- function(x, ignore=NULL) {
  if (is.null(ignore)) {
    sum(is.na(x))
  } else
  {
    sum(is.na(x[-(ignore)]))
  }
}

cntNA(x)
#[1] 3

cntNA(x, ignore=c(5,7))
#[1] 1
```

Comment: Just beat me to it. : )

Comment: What if I want to leave "ignore" blank and not ignore any of the indices? Thanks for your help!

Comment: I just realized `cntNA <- function(x, ignore = 0) sum(is.na(x)) - sum(is.na(x[ignore]))` works without `if`/`else`